# Python Faster way to do permutations

Tags: python, permutation

I'm trying to do a permutation of 32 items, and I'll pass each permutation into a function to do some calculations on each item in the permutation.

I left it to run for about 6 hours and I cancelled it. Is there a faster way?

Comment: No man. 32! is a huge number

Comment: Individually naming every grain of sand on the planet will take a long time regardless of whether you use short or long names. Same principle here.

Comment: `32! = 2.6313084e+35`, you may estimate how quick each function should be for it to work

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try something else.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you could pass 1 billion permutations into your function each second.  (N.B. you can't).

Now suppose that you left it running for the age of the universe:

```
13,700,000,000 (years) times 31,536,000 (seconds in a year)

(1000000000 * 31536000 * 13700000000) / 32! = 0.000000002
```

You will only be 0.0000002 % of the way through your calculation.

I recommend stopping it now and working out why you needed to do this, and whether you can solve your problem a different way.  (If it was just for fun, then maybe pick a smaller number).

Comment: I have stopped it. It turns out I didn't need `permutations`
In my outcome, I expect BAC = CBA. But I want to make sure that each one of the 32 items interact with every other item so i did this instead
`for lenght in range(2, len(items)):
 for item in combinations(items, lenght):
  calc_rate(item)`